# How to make the below div style in css

Tags: html, css

[image]

How to make the div list from left to right and after certain element it need to list from right to left again after certain element it need to be left to right so on.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: This is very easy to do post your code.

Comment: can you check now and help me

Comment: This is a very poor effort seems you want free work.  This is a site where we help people who at least try.  You have no styles at all...

Answer (score -1):

Try to create div groups. One left aligned and second right.

```
<div class="align-left">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="align-right">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

Comment: the div stucture is not defined like 3 form left 3 form right

Comment: its like list if its reached to the end it need to start from right and again if it reached end at left it need to start form left

Comment: I see your code structure but you should change it. This is not hard thing you should handle it.

Comment: can you give the solution please